Are we all descendants of Noah and his sons?
If the Bible story of the great flood is true, then unless the flood did not kill all human and animal life other than the occupants of the ark, is it Christian belief that all human cultures of the earth such as those in Mongolia, China, Southeast Asia, India, Pakistan and the West are also descendants of Noah and his sons? Making us all the chosen people of God?
How does the Christian faith reconcile this problem?
Or are we all descendants of the Mitochondrial Eve as genetic science has determined?

This question might be too generic for the site.  Asking "How does the Christian Faith"... isn't something we deal with here since this site covers all Christian denominations who have varying levels of biblical literalism. However, I think the answer you got was a pretty good overview answer so if you could make your question an overview question (explicitly) that would be much appreciated

It's unclear what "problem" is being asserted here?

"Making us all the chosen people of God?" — How does everyone's being a descendant of Noah make them "chosen people of God"?

There are 5 different questions asked here. Pick one, delete the others, and if warranted ask them in 4 separate questions. ¶ As it stands, one could simply reply "yes" to the Title question and ignore the rest as confusing noise.

"How does the Christian faith reconcile this problem?" — Don't make us guess what you thing "this problem" is; state it explicitly and explain why it is a problem.

Related: https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2002/05/the-royal-we/302497/ TLDR, it's likely that all living people today are descendants of any notable person from a few thousand years ago who has living descendants today. In other words, we're almost certainly all descendants of Noah, even if more than his family survived the flood. It's likely that we're all descendants of Abraham, too.

Firstly, let's understand what scientists mean by mitochondrial Eve: Mitochondrial Eve is simply the last matrilineal ancestor of all living humans. By definition, we are all descendants of her. The only way for this to be untrue is if there is no woman from whom all humans can trace matrilineal ancestry, in which case there is no mitochondrial Eve. However, no-one believes this. Traditionalists and secular scientists alike believe very strongly that all people are descended from a common ancestor.
The same is true patrilineally, and the most recent patrilineal ancestor of all living humans is called Y-chromosomal Adam. Just like mitochondrial Eve, we are all descendants of Y-chromosomal Adam by definition, unless of course the notion that all humans are descended from a common ancestor is false. If all humans are descendants of Noah, then this would make Noah the Y-chromosomal Adam.
Obviously, we shouldn't confused mitochondrial Eve and Y-chromosomal Adam with the Biblical Adam and Eve! There's no reason to suppose even that mitochondrial Eve and Y-chromosomal Adam were a couple, or that they lived in the same time period at all.
What do Christians believe?
The Bible teaches that Noah's Flood was God's act of judgment on the earth, and that there were only eight survivors (see Genesis 6-9 and especially 2 Peter 2:5), namely Noah and his wife and their three sons and their three wives. If this is true, then everyone is descended from Noah--he is Y-chromosomal Adam! However, Noah's wife is not mitochondrial Eve because Noah's daughters-in-law were not her daughters so not everyone is matrilineally descended from Noah's wife.
The Bible itself actually makes this point in Genesis 10, which is often called the "Table of Nations": All peoples around the world are descended from Noah. Genesis 10 records all the people-groups that the original readers would have known about and traces their ancestry back to Noah.
Therefore all people are chosen by God in the sense that we all partake in the covenant that God made with Noah in Genesis 9 - this is God's promise that he will never again wipe out the earth by a flood. If you read the rest of Genesis, you will see that from among the descendants of Noah, God chose Abraham to make a new special covenant with. Among the children of Abraham, God chose Isaac. And of Isaac, God chose Jacob and named him "Israel". Etc. Throughout history, God has chosen people for various purposes and in various ways.
Ephesians 1-2 tells how God has, in Christ, chosen us (meaning Christians) for salvation. God has called people from every tribe and nation (Rev.5:9-10). God's calling is not a matter of descent (Romans 9:6-7, Galatians 3:6-9), nor of merit on our part (Ephesians 2:8-9, Romans 3:20-31) but rather of God's mercy (Romans 9:16).
Paul summarizes this elegantly in 2nd Timothy 1:9-10:

He has saved us and called us to a holy life—not because of anything we have done but because of his own purpose and grace. This grace was given us in Christ Jesus before the beginning of time, but it has now been revealed through the appearing of our Savior, Christ Jesus, who has destroyed death and has brought life and immortality to light through the gospel.

Of course, there are many senses in which one can be "chosen by God". For Christians, the most important "chosen" is those who are saved through Christ (and the fact that it is God's choice does not mean anyone is barred. Anyone who comes to Christ will be saved. Jesus declares: "All that the Father gives me will come to me, and whoever comes to me I will never cast out." (John 6:37)). But some are also chosen for special ministries within the Church (such as Paul, Galatians 1:15-16) or for other purposes, such as Cyrus (Isaiah 45:1). God can even "choose" a worm (Jonah 4:7).
Other Christian views on Noah's Flood
There are some Christians who believe that Noah's Flood did not cover the earth or did not wipe out all people who were alive at the time (except those on the ark). I formerly believed that, but I changed my mind on the basis largely of 1st Peter 3:20 and 2nd Peter 2:5, which teach that there were only 8 survivors. In hindsight, I see now also that the point of Genesis 10 is negated if we don't believe that everyone is descended from Noah.
There are also Christians who would take the story of Noah's Flood wholly allegorically. This seems unreasonable to me for a couple reasons. Firstly, we see the Jesus's ancestry is traced by to Noah (Luke 3:23-36). How can a real person be the offspring of an allegorical person? It doesn't make any sense. (I am indebted to St. Augustine for this argument, see On the Literal Meaning of Genesis Book VIII chapter 4.)
Furthermore, taking the story as mere allegory does not do justice to the way it is used in 2 Peter 3:5-6:

For they deliberately overlook this fact, that the heavens existed long ago, and the earth was formed out of water and through water by the word of God, and that by means of these the world that then existed was deluged with water and perished.

(Note: the word "fact" isn't used in the Greek but has been introduced by the translators for the sake of English grammar, but the point Peter is making here is substantially neutered if the flood is understood as mere allegory. If the world didn't actually perish in the time of Noah, why would that story be a proof that God can execute judgment on the earth again?)


All human cultures of the earth such as those in Mongolia, China, Southeast Asia, India, Pakistan and the West are also descendants of Noah and his sons?

Correct. More specifically, these people are the result of the dispersion triggered by the Tower of Babel incident (see Genesis 11).

Making us all the chosen people of God?

What does "the chosen people of God" mean? If it means we are called by God to be His Children, then every person, especially every person since Christ, is "chosen".
If you mean according to a Covenant... which one? The one with Noah? Then, yes, we are all under that Covenant. (That Covenant in particular was made with all of humanity... granting that, at the moment it was made, "all of humanity" consisted of a whole eight individuals.) If the one with Abraham, or Isaac/Israel (subsequently the nation of Israel), then no; there were many other people alive by then who were descendants of Noah but were not included in those Covenants.

Or are we all descendants of the Mitochondrial Eve as genetic science has determined?

It's interesting to note that genetic "Eve" is date-estimate (by sources that aren't ignoring or distorting the results in order to avoid obviously contradicting Common Descent, i.e. the false, Scripture-denying idea that humans are descended from single-celled organisms) to about 4,000 BC, while genetic "Adam" is dated (same caveat) to only about 2,500 BC. This happens to be perfectly consistent with Scripture, which asserts (via genealogies) that Creation happened about 4,000 BC, and that Noah and his sons (who would obviously have inherited their father's Y chromosome) were the only male survivors of the Flood, making Eve (c. 4,000 BC) and Noah (c. 2,500 BC) the female and male "sole genetic ancestors", respectively.
Yes, we are all descendants of Adam and Eve, and of Noah, as Scripture teaches, and as science affirms.
On a related note, if you're interested in the genetic study of populations within a Scriptural context, I would recommend the book Traced by Nathaniel Jeanson, as well as his several videos published on the Answers in Genesis channel. (In particular, this playlist relates to the book, specifically, while this one contains additional videos. There is a third, dealing specifically with the early Americans, but that list seems to be a subset of the second one.)

Can you clarify what you mean by "Common Descent" in the third-to-last paragraph? (I think I know what you mean, but there is no disagreement that the human race is descended from a common ancestor.)

@DarkMalthorp, done. You're right, I'm using it in the sense that your ancestor was a fish, not in the sense that all humans are descended from a single pair. (Which... is actually a really odd thing for believers in CD to accept.)
